# C++ style Logger that supports __LINE__ macro and others

Tags: c++, logging, operator-overloading, endl

I want to make a Logger that can be used like `std::cout`, but I want to log some extra data like date, time, `__LINE__`, `__func__`, and `__FILE__` which should be saved to the file automatically.

### Example

```
ToolLogger log;
log << "some data" << std::endl;
```

### Expected output

```
[14.11.2015 21:10:12.344 (main.cpp) (main,14): some data
```

### Inadequate solution

To do this I have to put macros like `__LINE__` direct in the line where I call my logger, otherwise the macros won't work correct. I found that I can replace `std::endl` with my macro that will do this black magic like this:

```
#define __FILENAME__ (strrchr(__FILE__,'/') ? strrchr(__FILE__,'/') + 1 : __FILE__)
#define logendl \
    ((ToolLogger::fileName = __FILENAME__).empty() ? "" : "") \
    << ((ToolLogger::line = __LINE__) ? "" : "") \
    << ((ToolLogger::function = __func__).empty() ? "" : "") \
    << std::endl
```

The macro `logendl` uses static variables from my `ToolLogger` class to save the values of `__LINE__`, `__func__` and `__FILE__` needed later. So actually using the logger will looks like this:

```
ToolLogger log;
log << "some data" << logendl;
```

In the class i have to overload the `operator<<` to get this to work, and I need two of them. One for taking the normal values like `std::string` or `int`, and the other to take the `std::endl` manipulator. Here is the most important things from my class:

```
class ToolLogger
{
  public:

    // standard operator<< //
    template<typename T>
    ToolLogger& operator<< (const T& str)
    {
        out << str;
        return *this;
    }

    // operator<< for taking the std::endl manipulator //
    typedef std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > CoutType;
    typedef CoutType& (*StandardEndLine)(CoutType&);
    ToolLogger& operator<<(StandardEndLine manip)
    {
        // save fileName, line and function to the file //
        // and all what is already in stringstream //
        // clear stringstream //
        return *this;
    }

    static string fileName;
    static int line;
    static string function;

  private:

    ofstream file;
    std::stringstream out;
};

string ToolLogger::fileName;
int ToolLogger::line;
string ToolLogger::function;
```

### Problem

The problem in this solution is that I can use my logger in two ways:

```
log << "some data" << logendl;   // correct //
log << "some data" << std::endl; // compiles -> wrong /
```

So actually I need to remove the `operator<<` from my class that takes `std::endl` manipulator, and solve it other way, but how to do it? I was thinking about changing `std::endl` in `logendl` macro to other custom manipulator, and then this custom manipulator will do the work that is actually doing the `operator<<`, but I have no idea how to do it. I'm looking for other solution, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I do.  It kind of skirts your question.  That is, is does away with having to define an `endl`.  What I do is separate out a `Logger` class (which just takes strings and outputs then to wherever you need them to go) from a `LogMessage` class which builds a message.

The benefits are:

- Each class, on it's own, is pretty simple.
- Very simple macros.  I don't define the macro below but it's easy enough to do.
- No need to define an `endl`.  The message ends at the semicolon when the LogMessage class destructs

Let me know what you think:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

// logger class
// this is not complete, it exists just to illustrate the LogIt function
class Logger
{
public:
    void LogIt(const std::string & s)
    {
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }
};

// builds a logging message; outputs it in the destructor
class LogMessage
{
public:
    // constructor
    // takes identifying info of message.  You can add log level if needed
    LogMessage(const char * file, const char * function, int line)
    {
        os << file << ": " << function << '('  << line << ") ";
    }

    // output operator
    template<typename T>
    LogMessage & operator<<(const T & t)
    {
        os << t;
        return *this;
    }

    // output message to Logger
    ~LogMessage()
     {
         Logger logger; // get logger here (perhaps it's a singleton?)
         logger.LogIt(os.str());
     }
private:
     std::ostringstream os;
};

int main()
{
// example usage
// typically this is invoked via a simple macro to reduce typing of the LogMessage constructor
LogMessage(__FILE__, __func__, __LINE__) << "this is an int " << 5;
}
```

Comment: Well, I think this is some solution, I will be thinking about it, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might have a `LoggerAt` class with a `LoggerAt(const char*filename, int lineno)` constructor (perhaps a subclass of `std::ostringstream`, etc...), then define

```
#define LOG(Out) do {LoggerAt(__FILE__,__LINE__) \
  << Out << std::endl; }while(0)
```

In some of my C++ projects I have coded:

```
void mom_inform_at(const char*fil, int lin, std::ostringstream& out)
{ out.flush(); 
  std::clog << fil << ":" << lin 
            << " INFORM: " << out.str() << std::endl ;
}

#define MOM_INFORM_AT(Fil,Lin,Output) do {      \
      std::ostringstream out_##Lin;               \
        out_##Lin << mom_outlog << Output ;       \
        mom_inform_at(Fil,Lin,out_##Lin);         \
    } while(0)

  #define MOM_INFORM_AT_BIS(Fil,Lin,Output) \
    MOM_INFORM_AT(Fil,Lin,Output)

  #define MOM_INFORM(Out)                         \
    MOM_INFORM_AT_BIS(__FILE__,__LINE__,Out)
```

And using something like `MOM_INFORM("x=" << " point:" << pt);` where you could imagine the usual `Point pt;` example with appropriate `std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream&out, const Point&point)` function.

Notice that to use *conveniently* `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` you'll better use macros.

Comment: Thank You, I will check your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my own problem. Other answers posted here may be better than main, but I wanted to use logger in a simple way just like in C++ `std::cout` is used. Also my solution may not be optimal and may lead to other problems, but it meets my requirements.

I have added a custom `std::ostream`

```
class CustomOstream : public std::ostream
{
  public:

    static CustomOstream& endl( CustomOstream& out )
    {
        return out;
    }
};
```

and changed macro to use the `endl` function from `CustomOstream`

```
#define __FILENAME__ (strrchr(__FILE__,'/') ? strrchr(__FILE__,'/') + 1 : __FILE__)
#define logendl \
    ((ToolLogger::fileName = __FILENAME__).empty() ? "" : "") \
    << ((ToolLogger::line = __LINE__) ? "" : "") \
    << ((ToolLogger::function = __func__).empty() ? "" : "") \
    << ToolLogger::CustomOstream::endl
```

Also the `operator<<` from the main class has been changed

```
ToolLogger& operator<< (CustomOstream& (*f)(CustomOstream&))
{
    // do something //
    return *this;
}
```

Now the logger can be used just like I wanted

```
log << "some data" << logendl;   // correct //
log << "some data" << std::endl; // won't compile -> correct //
```