# Evaluate C macro __LINE__ inside another macro

Tags: c, macros

I'd like to create a macro whose *value* is the evaluation of `__LINE__` at a certain point so that I can do the following:

```
#define LINE1 __LINE__
int a[] = {
1,
2,
3
};
#define LINE2 __LINE__
printf("There are %d rows", LINE2 - LINE1 - 2);
```

...but `LINE2` and `LINE1` end up giving me the line number of the `printf` statement. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you do `const int blah = __LINE__;` instead?

Comment: You can't do it that way.  I'm not sure you can do it at all.  The `#define LINE1` simply says 'when you see `LINE1`, replace it with `__LINE__`.  But `__LINE__` evaluates to the line number where `LINE1` is used, not where it is defined.  Besides, the correct way to determine the number of elements in an array is `(sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]))` — which works correctly even if someone places two entries on a single line, or adds a comment in the middle of the list, etc.  The only time that it fails is when the 'array' is actually a pointer parameter to a function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33712984/841108 could inspire you

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: That creates a variable. C does not have symbolic constants.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler +1 for noticing, what OP is actually trying to do

Comment: `enum { line_x = __LINE__ };`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Macro Expansion is a lazy and recursive process. It lazy because when you define a macro with `#define` it is not evaluated where you have defined it; rather, it will be replaced with its value where you used it. And this replacement will take place recursively until it is replaced with something that is not a macro. So,

```
printf("There are %d rows", LINE2 - LINE1 - 2);
```

will be expanded to

```
printf("There are %d rows", __LINE__ - __LINE__ - 2);
```

which in turn will be expanded to

```
printf("There are %d rows", N - N - 2); // N being the current line number.
```

You can change your code as suggested by HolyBlackCat. Instead of declaring macro using `#define` use `const int`.

```
const int LINE1 = __LINE__;
   .
   .
   .
const int LINE2 = __LINE__;
```

Answer (score 3):

Silly hack:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
struct yyy{ char buff[__LINE__ ]; } ;
#define LINE1 ((int)sizeof(struct yyy))
int a[] = {
1,
2,
3,
4
};
struct zzz{ char buff[__LINE__ ]; } ;
#define LINE2 ((int)sizeof(struct zzz))
printf("[%d,%d]There are %d rows\n", LINE1 , LINE2 , LINE2 - LINE1 - 4);

return 0;
}
```

---

And it works at file scope,too:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct yyy{ char buff[__LINE__ ]; } ;
#define LINE1 ((int)sizeof(struct yyy))
int a[] = {
1,
2,
4
};
struct zzz{ char buff[__LINE__ ]; } ;
#define LINE2 ((int)sizeof(struct zzz))

int main(void)
{
printf("[%d,%d]There are %d rows\n", LINE1 , LINE2 , LINE2 - LINE1 - 4);

return 0;
}
```

---

NOTE:this does not create variables, only two (unused) structure types.

---

Yet another ugly trick: use enums (which are not objects, but constants_in_disguise):

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum { OMG=__LINE__ , } ;
int a[] = {
#define INDEX(ll) ( (ll)- ((OMG)+3))
INDEX(__LINE__),
INDEX(__LINE__),
INDEX(__LINE__),
INDEX(__LINE__),
INDEX(__LINE__),
INDEX(__LINE__)
};
enum { WTF=__LINE__ , } ;

int main(void)
{
printf("[%d,%d]There are %d rows\n", OMG , WTF , WTF - OMG - 4);

return 0;
}
```